# What is google api redirect uri

Tags: python, google-api

I would like to know what exactly should we prefill while giving redirect uri in Google API console.

When I try to specify localhost:8080 I am advised to proceed but not with any other address.

Answer (score 0):

This redirect URI is for performing a web-based OAuth 2.0 flow. From the [OAuth 2.0 docs](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#formingtheurl):

> Determines where the response is sent. The value of this parameter
>   must exactly match one of the values registered in the [APIs
>   Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console#access) (including the http or https schemes, case, and trailing
>   '/').